# How to get my free Origin copy of Battlefield 1942 to run

Tags: windows-7, origin, battlefield-1942

Origin accounts have a free version of Battlefield 1942 available to download and play through their software but when I try to run it I get the Microsoft circle of patience (mouse circle showing activity) but then it disappears and the game/origin doesn't do anything.

I have tried to turn off the antivirus and firewall and run Origin and battlefield as Administrator but does not work.

I am running Windows 7 64Bit Ultimate 8GB RAM using NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M on an Acer Aspire 5755G. Everything is updated.

Answer (score 1):

[PCGamingWiki.com](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Battlefield_1942) is a good place to start.

> Attempt 1: Run the game as an Administrator in Windows 98 Compatibility mode
>
> In your Battlefield 1942 folder, Right click BF1942.exe->Go to Compatibility Tab
>
> 1. Check "Run this program in compatibility mode for" and select Windows 98
> 2. Check "Run as Administrator"
> 3. Click OK
>
> Compatibility mode should fix the crashes, however sometimes Punkbuster doesn't like it and boots you a few seconds after joining. If this is the case, Turn off compatibility mode and proceed to Attempt 2.
>
> Note, this method is recommended if you are experiencing crashes for the Origin version of the game. It is also suggested you try the other compatibility modes if Windows 98 does not fix the problem.
>
> Attempt 2: Pixel-Fighter Windows Vista/7 Patch
>
> BF42 Player Grabbi (server admin/creator of Forgotten Hope Mod fan community Pixel-Fighter) has developed a patch which changes some game files and registry entries to fix crashing and eliminate the need for compatibility mode in Windows Vista/Windows 7 (thus fixing Punkbuster kicks because of it). It also adds some Widescreen resolutions (up to 1600x1200) and lowers abnormally high pings on Windows Vista/7 that some have reported. **This should be a last resort since it permanently changes Windows registry entries and game files.**
>
> [Pixel-Fighter Windows Vista/Windows 7 Patch Info](http://www.pixel-fighter.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=253)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will take a look at that tonight and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Just an update for all those interested. I have not managed to get the above answer to work for me. It doesn't mean it wont for you but was not the fix in my case.

Comment: @WillNZ That's unfortunate :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that affects both physical disc copies and digital copies of the game.

I think that this is a secuROM (outdated security DRM checker) problem. I think that Microsoft disabled the part of Windows that lets secuROM to run and check to see if you own the game. Since it cannot run, I think that the game does not run, because it never gets a confirmed yes or no from the software.

I had this problem also, and I found a video on how to fix it about a year ago, but YouTube has since decided to take it down. Another video that I found helpful:

This video details one way of counter-acting the problem. Another way is just deleting some KB update from your computer that Microsoft has distributed, but that would leave your computer open to viruses that exploit the old DRM checker.

You have two options for fixing/solving this problem (both of these methods solve the problem for the physical disc copies of the game and the virtual downloaded versions from Origin or elsewhere online):

Option 1:

Step 1:
You open cmd (command prompt on windows) with administrative privileges, and type in "sc start secdrv" (exactly how you see it, and yes an extra space could mess it up) and press enter.

Step 2:
Try opening the game up now with administrative privileges. If it works, congratulations! If it doesn't try researching another solution to the problem of secuROM.

Step 3:
After you close the game you need to reopen cmd with administrative privileges and type "sc stop secdrv" to stop the process, so you are less likely to get a virus from leaving secuROM on.

Option 2:

You can open the registry editor and delete the Microsoft security patch (It will forever leave your PC vunerable to viruses, but at least you don't have to worry about starting and stopping the secuROM process.)

This website link details how to perform both options:

https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2015/09/23/windows-update-disables-safedisc-drm-7-8-vista/

As far as I can tell, the actions needed to start, stop and delete the update work on safeDisk (another form of old DRM software) and secuROM.

Sorry if this was a little long, but I wanted to provide as much information and as many solutions as possible to this problem since it took me 1 full day of research for me to figure out why my disk copy wasn't starting after a Microsoft update.

Answer (score -2):

check your graphics card. Some games don't run if its not that well. But If you could run other demanding games I guess that might not be the problem.